# Bulk export from marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I have an xquery written to export a main file and its related files as a  zip file from Marklogic. Now I have a requirement where i need to export bulk of such files. So obvious approach I am thinking of is zip of zip files.
To explain precisely Say there are 2 files that needs to be exported A, and B and each of these two files might have some sub files associated to it say 
A has three sub files namely A1, A2 and A3 similarly B has 2 sub files namely B1 and B2. So my idea is to create a zip of each file and its sub files and finally one zip file out of all the zip files.

```
Zip-->zip1-->(A,A1,A2,A3)
   -->zip2-->(B,B1,B2)
```

Want to know if this approach is good or are there any other better bulk export approaches available.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where you are not just bulk exporting A and B, but perhaps half a million A/B-like files. You'd be creating half a million zip files, but also wrap that in one humongous zip file. Sounds like you should consider processing your files in batches, and return multiple zip files, each containing something between 10 to 1000 files. How much exactly could depend on how much memory your system has. Consider the idea of creating batches that run and create zipfiles in parallel.

Zips in zips sounds like overkill too, you could use folders inside zips as well. But apart from that, it should work.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that nested zips are probably unnecessary. As far as export goes in general, there is no need to reinvent the wheel: take a look at http://marklogic.github.com/xqsync/ and http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ingestion/content-pump

Answer (score 0):

Also realize that there is a 4G maximum size for zip files or the files they contain.
This could thwart your idea of one massive zip.